# wget always going some other IP not the requested IP

Tags: 16.04, wget

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and i want to `wget` some file from my another PC connected in same network.

**My PC-1 IP is 192.168.1.210** &

**My PC-2 IP is 192.168.1.209**.

Trying to get a file in 192.168.1.209 from the folder path is `/var/www/` and file name is "mydoc"

```
root@OptiPlex-980:~# wget http://192.168.1.209/mydoc
--2017-12-07 16:08:45--  http://192.168.1.209/mydoc
Connecting to 10.102.0.3:80...
```

I uninstalled the `wget` package using "`apt remove wget && apt purge wget`".
Then reinstalled again using "`apt install wget`"
But I am still observing like `Connecting to 10.102.0.3:80...` not the IP I am requesting.

But I am trying from PC-2 to PC-1 it works fine.

What is the problem with this PC ? `wget` config ?

Comment: what is the out put of `nslookup`of both the IP

Comment: `root@OptiPlex-980:~# nslookup localhost`

`Server:  8.8.8.8`
`Address: 8.8.8.8#53`

`** server can't find localhost: NXDOMAIN`

PC-2

`root@OptiPlex-980:~# nslookup 192.168.1.209`
`Server:  8.8.8.8`
`Address: 8.8.8.8#53`
`** server can't find 209.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN`

Comment: Maybe `http_proxy`?

Comment: Sounds to me like there are redirects on your other server. Try `wget --max-redirect 0`

Comment: But its not redirecting to other IP it is requesting to another IP Thats the problem

Comment: Did you try or did you just answer without trying? If nothing else just use an `scp 192.168.1.209:/var/www/mydoc .`

Comment: I tried and output is `root@OptiPlex-980:~# wget --max-redirect 0 http://192.168.1.209/1GB
--2017-12-07 16:46:05--  http://192.168.1.209/1GB
Connecting to 10.102.0.3:80... `

Comment: I still think your webserver on that one host is configured to relink/redirect all access to port 80 to 10.102.0.3 you should check your config there, apache/nginx or whatever other webserver you're using.

Comment: are you able to `ping` the ip 192.168.1.209

Comment: Apache2 i have and that looks fine

Comment: I can able to ping, ssh, telnet and ftp to the PC-2 from PC-1 and vice versa. But wget from PC-1 is always requesting to 10.102.0.3:80

Comment: whatever http I am requesting from terminal its always going to 10.102.0.3:80

Comment: Check your http request using `httpry`

To install: `sudo apt-get install httpry`

Use this command to and share the output: `sudo httpry -i interface-name`

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, that your webserver at PC-2 is not follwoing a redirect, check with cURL:

> curl - v http://192.168.1.209/mydoc

and read closely through the verbose output; You should see something like this in the beginning:

```
* About to connect() to 192.168.1.209 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.1.209... connected
* Connected to 192.168.1.209 port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Now, the important part is the server response, either:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

or

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://10.102.0.3:80
```

Please post your cURL output for further help.

Check if you have set http_proxy environment variables; wget evaluates http_proxy and HTTP_PROXY. If you are not sure call wget with the '--no-proxy' option

Comment: i just checked the PC-1's wget config and changed to all default settings and restarted the interface then it works. Thank you all for your inputs.